# How to create table in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, heidisql

When I try to create simple table via `HeidiSQL` I'm getting an error like this

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `prg_config` (
    `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `value` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT ''
) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

Comment: specify length for `varchar` for `value` column

Comment: Also, the `PRIMARY KEY` must not be `NOT NULL`.  (Make the change on the `id` line.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of making a screenshot of a message dialog, you can press Ctrl+C to copy the text contents of that box to your clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

Please Check Following query :

```
CREATE TABLE prg_config (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
     `value` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `prg_config` (
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
        `value` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT ''
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

1. Add `PRIMARY KEY`/`UNIQUE`/`KEY` to `AUTO_INCREMENT` column
2. Specify length for [`VARCHAR`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/varchar/).

> **[AUTO_INCREMENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment/)** :
>
> Each table can have only one AUTO_INCREMENT column. It must defined as
>   a key (not necessarily the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE key). If the key
>   consists of multiple columns, the AUTO_INCREMENT column must be the
>   first one, unless the storage engine is Aria or MyISAM.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/014827)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you created that table with HeidiSQL's table designer, I guess it looked like this:

[image]

HeidiSQL does not complain when you make the length/set empty for a `VARCHAR` column. MySQL + MariaDB both require a length for `VARCHAR` columns, so I can probably fix that by not letting the user to make the `VARCHAR` length empty.

Comment: I fixed that in [r5032 of HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php#r5032), so that you get an error message saying _Column data type %s requires a length/set_ when you try to leave an empty length/set value for a VARCHAR column.